# How to keep STDIN at bottom the terminal in C

Tags: c, io, terminal, stdin, instant-messaging

I am writing a simple instant messaging client in c. It's currently working well, however if a user is typing and receives a message while typing, the message displays AFTER the text, then the user continues on the line below. It would look like this:

> USER: I am trying to ty...FRIEND: Hello
>
> pe a message.  <--- (the end of the users message)

My idea is:

Somehow force the current data from stdin and load it into a buffer, then use a \r before printing FRIEND: to erase what is on the line, then print from the buffer. Does anyone have any concrete examples of how to accomplish this task?

The final result should be

> FRIEND:  Hello
>
> USER: I am trying to type a message

The user started typing the message, received a message, the stdin line was shifted downwards, then the user completed their message.

Note: I am running GNOME Terminal 3.6.2 on the newest version of Linux Mint

Comment: You might want to read about [the ncurses library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses), or about using [VT100 control codes](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm) to put the cursor at the position.

Comment: There is no way to do this with pure standard C. C doesn't even recognize the presence of a terminal or even a computer screen: it is only concerned with input and output streams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to do this is using [ncurses](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/) (any flavor of curses would work), accepting the input in one *window* and writing the result to *another*.  Here is a short example:

```
#include <curses.h>

int
main(void)
{
    bool done = FALSE;
    WINDOW *input, *output;
    char buffer[1024];

    initscr();
    cbreak();
    echo();
    input = newwin(1, COLS, LINES - 1, 0);
    output = newwin(LINES - 1, COLS, 0, 0);
    wmove(output, LINES - 2, 0);    /* start at the bottom */
    scrollok(output, TRUE);
    while (!done) {
    mvwprintw(input, 0, 0, "> ");
    if (wgetnstr(input, buffer, COLS - 4) != OK) {
        break;
    }
    werase(input);
    waddch(output, '\n');   /* result from wgetnstr has no newline */
    waddstr(output, buffer);
    wrefresh(output);
    done = (*buffer == 4);  /* quit on control-D */
    }
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to learn about VT100 control codes (as distinct from ECMA-48), [vt100.net](http://vt100.net/) has manuals for some terminals.

Regarding the link *[VT100 control codes](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm)*: that is a source of misinformation, as noted in the ncurses FAQ *[How do I get color with VT100?](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#vt100_color)*